# AutoCompleteTextView on selection gives StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have an AutoCompleteTextView, that uses a dynamic adapter. On selecting an item from the drop down list, a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException is raised.

The exception seems to happening depending upon the contents of the String added to the adapter.
Here's is what I found out:

1. Adding a , or . or ( breaks the code.
2. Adding a long string breaks the code.
3. Adding a digit breaks the code.
4. Adding a space breaks the code.

Here's the onPostExecute code of my AsyncTask:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

Log.i("","onPostExecute");

ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
test.add(new String("Microsoft"));
test.add(new String("Tesla"));
test.add(new String("Google"));

String str_JSON = result.substring(result.indexOf("(") + 1, result.lastIndexOf(")"));

Log.i("", "JSON obtained: " + str_JSON);

try {

    JSONObject obj_JSON = new JSONObject(str_JSON);
    JSONArray arr_JSON = obj_JSON.getJSONObject("ResultSet").getJSONArray("Result");

    Log.i("", "arr_JSON Length: " + arr_JSON.length());

    for(int index = 0; index < arr_JSON.length(); index++) {

        JSONObject row_JSON = arr_JSON.getJSONObject(index);

        String str_autocomplete = row_JSON.getString("symbol") 
        + ", " + row_JSON.getString("name")                             
        + " (" + row_JSON.getString("exch") + ")";                          

        test.add(new String(str_autocomplete));
    }

    Log.i("", "list_autocomplete Length: " + COMPANIES.size());

} catch (Exception e) {};           

adapter.clear();
adapter.addAll(test);

Log.i("", "adapter Count: " + adapter.getCount());

AutoCompleteTextView t = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.text_company);
t.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

So, how to build the String so that AutoCompleteTextView won't break?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't write comments because of low reputation, so I'm writing this as an answer... Why do you write `test.add(new String(str_autocomplete));` instead of just `test.add(str_autocomplete);`?

Comment: I was thinking there could be difference between String Objects and Sting Literals in this case, but there isn't.

Comment: Here - `String str_JSON = result.substring(result.indexOf("(") + 1, result.lastIndexOf(")"));` - can be thrown the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` in case of `indexOf` returns `-1`...

Comment: na. it isn't that code that is throwing the exception. thanks!